# Getting the first tuple of list of tuples in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I am trying to get the first element of a tuple for every tuple in a list using the following:

```
getRow :: [(Integer,Integer)] -> [(Integer,Integer)]
getRow (row:rows) = do
    (fst(head (row)))
```

I thought if I could get the first element of every head of the list of tuples that it would return just the first element, but that wasnt the case.

Comment: Being new to the language has nothing to do with this problem -- yet. First write down the steps you would take to achieve what you want if you had to do it by hand. Then try to translate each step into code. If you get stuck, you can ask us a specific question about one of the steps.

Comment: @Eric          what do you recommend I do as far as getting a kick start to learning the language? It's confusing to me coming from an imperative language programmer.

Comment: There are many good Haskell tutorials, like [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) or [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/). But the algorithm design process is identical in imperative and functional languages. You have to figure out what the algorithm is before you start implementing it.

Comment: @Eric        I have edited the problem done to a more specific example of what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks for you help!

Comment: It's a much better question now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, your expected output should be a list of elements, not a list of tuples. Therefore, the first step is to change the signature to:

```
getRow :: [(Integer,Integer)] -> [Integer]
```

But why restrict to `Integer`, when the method can work for any type? Let's make it more general by doing this:

```
getRow :: [(a,b)] -> [a]
```

Now the algorithm itself. You have the right idea about using `fst` to get the first element. We will use this function, together with a list comprehension to do the job as follows:

```
getRow lst = [fst x | x <- lst]
```

This will go through the list, extract the first element from each tuple and return a list of the extracted elements. Putting it all together, we get this:

```
getRow :: [(a,b)] -> [a]
getRow lst = [fst x | x <- lst]
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/OZEZ23522)

Of course, this is one of many possible ways to go about the problem. Another solution would be to use a `foldr` function to do the same thing, like so:

```
getRow2 :: [(a,b)] -> [a]
getRow2 lst = foldr (\x acc -> (fst x):acc) [] lst
```

You can start off with a good tutorial to learn about the basics of Haskell, and use [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/doc-index.html) for reference. However, @Eric is absolutely correct to say that in any paradigm, you need to figure out the steps first before you start to write the code.

Comment: wow thank you so much I appreciate the help and this reference will continue to help me in my future implementation of code! Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: The functional solution to this problem is `getRow3 = map fst`

Comment: Yes, I realised it after posting. Monday I guess :P